# Is there any groups for software development in ubuntu?

Tags: community

I am really willing to contribute to open-source software development. But the thing is, I am alone. Is there any groups in Ubuntu where I can share my idea, and I can be a beta-tester, or maybe make programs using ideas? I am really a new-bie, and I want to help the open-source community and become a member of it.

Comment: Maybe this: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/ and http://developer.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to AskUbuntu. The best place to start is the [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/); register there and share your ideas at the [Development & Programming](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=310) section.

You are not alone. Enjoy Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1):

Try to find nearby [Hackerspace](http://hackerspaces.org/wiki/List_of_Hacker_Spaces) or any [LUG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_User_Group) in your area. Also, Ubuntu supports [local communites](http://community.ubuntu.com/help-information/meeting-other-ubuntu-users/local-communities/).

Keep [googling](https://maps.google.com/) until you find a group in your area. Programming with people face-to-face is so much more rewarding than doing it home-alone.